# How to create DbProviderFactory object for SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to create an object for [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) using the following code,

```
 try
 {
     var sql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"];
     DbProviderFactory sqlfactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory ( sql.ProviderName ); // This one works fine

     var sqlCE = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlCE"];
     DbProviderFactory sqlCEfactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory ( sqlCE.ProviderName ); // This doesnt 
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
      Console.WriteLine ( ex.Message );
  }
```

and `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear/>
   <add name="sql" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=TestResults;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
   <add name="sqlCE" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe" 
        connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DataBase\dbTestResults.sdf"/>  
</connectionStrings>
```

The first one (`sqlFactory`) creates successfully, but the second object (`sqlCEfactory`) throws an exception:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong provider names specified in your config file.

The SQL Server CE invariant provider names are

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0
```

(for version 4.0 runtime)

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5
```

(for version 3.5 runtime)