# Ability to connect to SQL server and SQL server compact without modifying the code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, multiple-databases

I have built a vb.net application to work on one computer, so I used SQL server compact database.

Now I want the application to work over network with SQL server database without making anther copy of the application and modifying it.

For example how to handle the declarations

```
 Dim dr As SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader
```

I think the queries and all other codes will remain the same- please correct me if I am wrong-.

Thank you,

Comment: It's impossible to say whether anything else would need changing.  That should probably be the case but we couldn't say for sure without seeing them, which isn't appropriate for this site.  As for the provider, you can't use the `SqlServerCe` provider for SQL Server and you can't use the `SqlClient` provider for SQL Server CE.  If you want to support both then you would need to either have two sets of code or use the `OleDb` ADO.NET provider and then change the underlying OLE DB provider as required. That would probably mean changing the connection string in a config file.

Comment: Take a read of [Obtaining a DbProviderFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) and [How to create DbProviderFactory object for SQL Server CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488414/how-to-create-dbproviderfactory-object-for-sql-server-ce)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help.
I used DbProvidorFactory to handle the connection
[How to create DbProviderFactory object for SQL Server CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488414/how-to-create-dbproviderfactory-object-for-sql-server-ce)

The only I had to change in my code that SQL server compact does not support multiple SQL sentences such as

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
```

In that case I had to have two different insert sentence. one for each database type.